# Using jQuery .ajax() to send data to django view

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I have the following code to POST and send data to a django view. However request.POST is empty. I was expecting request.POST = {'keywoard':'test'} on server side.

```
  $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {'keywoard':'test'},
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert("done")
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is because you have set  `contentType: "application/json"`, so `request.POST` will be empty. You should remove that parameter so that it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Also, within data, do not put key in quotes. keyword, not 'keyword'.